# CGContextRelease - incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned

Tags: cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, quartz-graphics

I have seen a lot of questions on SO about this theme but they don't ask my case.

Analyzer is giving me this warning

**incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at that point by the caller**

but in my case the method in question is not generating or is not intended to return any context.

My method is like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGContextRef ctx;

- (void)generatePDFWithSize:(CGSize)size andURL:(NSURL*)url {

  CGRect mediaBox = CGRectZero;
  mediaBox.size = tamanho;

  self.ctx = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)(URL), &mediaBox, NULL);

  for (int i=0; i<numberOfPages; i++) {
     CGPDFContextBeginPage(self.ctx, NULL);
     //... bla bla bla... generate page
     CGPDFContextEndPage(self.ctx);
  }

  CGContextRelease(self.ctx);
}
```

Analyzer is pointing to the last line.

How do I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a separate reference to your Context such as:

```
CGContextRef ctx = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)(URL), &mediaBox, NULL);
self.ctx = ctx;
```

Then you can release the context that you've created by calling:

```
CFRelease (ctx);
```

So you're not releasing the one that the compiler believes that self owns.